# Configuring sqlalchemy engine with user containing ":"

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, amazon-redshift

I am trying to configure an engine in sqlalchemy to connect with temporary credentials from an AWS IAM role using get_cluster_credentials api.
When I do so this is the user I get 'IAM:user_rw'. Problem comes when I configure the engine string as

```
engine_string = "postgresql+pygresql://{user}:{password}@{endpoint}:{port}/{dbname}".format(
        user=cluster_creds['DbUser'],
        password=cluster_creds['DbPassword'],
        endpoint='big endpointstring',
        port=8192,
        dbname='small dbname')
```

I create the engine without errors but when running any query I get: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "IAM"
Tested the user and pass in DataGrip it works so it seems evident sqlalchemy is getting the user just as "IAM" instead of 'IAM:user_rw'.

Do you know how can I force sqlalchemy to get the correct user?

Comment: Just add a \  before `:` like this `IAM\:user_rw`

Comment: Im trying this so I changed `user=cluster_creds['DbUser']` for `user="IAM\:user_rw` but now engine string is showing  as `postgresql+pygresql://IAM\\:user_rw:etcetc`. so the error is now `FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "IAM\"`. How can I force to only interpret one \?

Comment: You can use [engine.URL.create](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/engines.html#sqlalchemy.engine.URL.create) to construct the connection URL/URI for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue using urllib [parse_quote](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.quote) in a similar fashion to what Gord is pointing. Final code

```
from urllib.parse import quote_plus
engine_string = "postgresql+pygresql://%s:%s@%s:%d/%s" % (
        quote_plus(user),
        quote_plus(passw),
        endpoint,
        port,
        dbname,
    )
```